# React - Redux-Form Remote Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am attempting to remotely submit a form using redux-forms. My question would be, how do I execute redux actions from a function outside the component. The equivalaent of saying:

> this.props.action(params);

My code is as follows:

```
async function submit(values) {
    return (
        //Equivalent of => this.props.addOne(values.name)
        await actions.addOne(values.name, 60)
    )
}

const renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error } }) =>
<TextField 
    autoFocus
    margin="dense"
    fullWidth
    type="text"
    label={label}
    {...input}
/>

class LibrarySubsectionForm extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field
                component={renderTextField}
                name="name" 
                label="Subsection Name"
            />
        </form>
    )
}
}

export default compose(
connect(null, actions),
reduxForm({ form: 'AddSubsection', onSubmit: submit })
)(LibrarySubsectionForm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux-form is passing `dispatch` function and `props` of your decorated component as second and third arguments of `onSubmit` handler. So basically you have access to them inside your `submit` function. If you are passing `actions` as a prop to `LibrarySubsectionForm` then you can access them inside `submit` function:

```
async function submit(values, dispatch, props) {
    return await props.actions.addOne(values.name, 60);
}
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. Thank you!